# open shell without permission on windows

Tags: windows, shell, terminal, restriction

I´m using a school computer, so I don´t own administrator permissions.
anyway I want to launch the command line, but since the school pc´s are restricted I don´t have the permission to install or launch software like terminal, powershell, system settings.
I´m sure that somehow I can create a batch file that allows me to open the shell, but since I don´t know DOS, I don´t exactly know how.
please help me, I´m not a hacker and don´t wanna damage the school computer system, It´s for ethical purpose only, but it could be useful to hit on girls XD.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it:

```
@echo off
:loop
set /p _cmd= “%CD%>”
%_cmd%
goto :loop
```

Comment: This solution is brilliant, validated and working. The next question is how we can change this code to get CMD running as admin...?